# Page does not show updated information after ajax call in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, unobtrusive-javascript

I have rails 3.1 and when I use ajax for delete operation, the page is not showing the updated content without a manual refresh.

The strange thing is that all the .js.erb code seems to be firing properly.  I even tried putting just a simple page.alert('hi') in the destroy.js.erb but I do not get any alert after the delete. I saw a couple of places where they mention adding a "script" tag for ajax in the view to make jquery work but none of the latest tutorials mention that. I will appreciate your help.

Here is what I see in the server logs:

```
Started DELETE "/categories/35" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-19 12:58:15 -0500
  Processing by CategoriesController#destroy as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"35"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 5 LIMIT 1
  Category Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."user_id" = 5 AND "categories"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "35"]]
  SQL (0.5ms)  DELETE FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" = ?  [["id", 35]]
Rendered categories/destroy.js.erb (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 161ms (Views: 30.7ms | ActiveRecord: 3.2ms)
```

Here is what I see in the generated html page output page source:

```
...
 <tr id = "category_35">
    <td>High-end products</td>
    <td class="deletebutton"><a href="/categories/35" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>

 <tr id = "category_36">
    <td>Economy products</td>
    <td class="deletebutton"><a href="/categories/36" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>
```

The content of destroy.js.erb:

```
('#<%= dom_id(@category) %>').fadeOut(700);
```

In Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

In categories_controller.rb:

```
  def index
      @categories = current_user.categories.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json 
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
      @category.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to categories_url }
        format.js { 
            render :template => 'categories/destroy.js.erb', :layout => false 
        }
    end
  end
```

In app/views/categories/index.html.erb

```
<h2>Categories</h2>
<table name="categories_list">
<%= render "categories_list" %>
</table>    
<br />
```

In the partial _categories_list.html.erb

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <tr id = "<%= dom_id(category)%>">
    <td><%= category.name %></td>

    <td class="deletebutton"><%= link_to 'Delete', category, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete, :remote => true  %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: how does your ajax call look like

Comment: I have not put any separate ajax call code. I am using the unobtrusive method.  As you can see I put :remote => true on the delete button. Does that help?

Comment: @3nigma, do I need to add any setup code in application.js?  I see some old tutorials mentioning ajax setup but do we need that with the latest rails 3.1?

Comment: i have no knowledge of rails so cant really help ya

Answer (score 1):

Ok, just in case someone stumbles on this question, I wanted to share the solution.  There were about 3 things of significance:

1. The $ sign in destroy.js.erb was missing. Here is the corrected code:

   $('#<%= dom_id(@category) %>').fadeOut(700);
2. Also, the controller must be instructed NOT to use the default layouts when responding to .js. This can be done in the applcation controller itself.  But I did it in the category controller as follows:

   respond_to do |format|
       format.html { redirect_to categories_url }
       format.json
       format.js {render "destroy", :layout => false}
3. Also, at one point during the iteration I had confused format.json with format.js.  They are two different things!  Since, I am new to RoR, I thought that the response to the ajax calls will be json and format.json is analogous to format. js.

Finally, i should give a shout out to Mark, who shared an ajax demo on github at:
https://github.com/markusproske/ajax_demo/tree/jquery

The additional change I had to do to make it work for me was disabling the layout rendition.  Otherwise, that demo is thorough.  I am still looking at handling error conditions for js calls.